# Why doesn't Ruby Qt clock update?

Tags: ruby, qt

I'm trying to write a custom clock widget in Ruby Qt `gem install qtbindings` The clock should update every second with the current time. It doesn't, the code seems perfect, why doesn't this work?

```
require "Qt4"

class ClockLabel < Qt::Label
    attr_accessor :timer
    def initialize(date_format = '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')
        super()
        @date_format = date_format
        self.set_text(Time.now.strftime date_format)
    end

    def paint_event(event)
        super(event)
        painter = Qt::Painter.new(self)
        painter.draw_text(event.rect.x, event.rect.y, Time.now.strftime(@date_format))
    end

    def start
        @timer = Qt::Timer.new(self)
        self.connect(@timer, SIGNAL('timeout()'), self, SLOT('update()'))
        @timer.start(1000)
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
    app = Qt::Application.new([])
    clock = ClockLabel.new()
    clock.start
    clock.show
    app.exec()
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I replace the `connect` call with

```
  @timer.connect(SIGNAL :timeout) {
    set_text(Time.now.strftime @date_format)
    update
  }
```

`paint_event` never gets called and can be omitted. That gives the hint that the widget did not change, so we change it when the timer triggers.

Comment: Thanks but why doesn't paint event get called?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm a beginner with Qt.